# I do not see uploaded video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have used
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

exactly videosInsertRequest.Upload instead async
so I have stopped at breakpoint after Upload() but do not see video at my_videos or in list https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#retrieve_my_uploads

Answer (score 0):

I think it is error api because it worked early and stopped. So I tried upload manually unsuccessfully. May be I rich limit and api do not notify me. So I think need upgrade api to generate exception or other notification.